# Nomenclature of Interstellar Objects and Stars

Tags: asteroid, terminology, stars

I tried searching the answer to this on Google for hours and visited the IAU website as well, but it didn't really clarify my doubt. I was reading about Black Widow Pulsar, which is an "eclipsing binary millisecond pulsar in the Milky Way" and after its common name, in brackets is given **PSR B1957+20**. How is this named? What nomenclature rules are used? Was this the provisional name given before it was named Black Widow Pulsar or is this the scientific name of the neutron star?

This is the case with most interstellar objects and stars. Like Ultima Thule has another name 486958 Arrokoth? Is this a scientific name? Please explain what nomenclature conventions are used to name the asteroids and stars

Comment: This is certainly very on-topic in Astronomy SE, but how solar system bodies are named *by Astronomers* is really not on-topic here in Space Exploration. I think this will be quickly closed here and probably migrated to Astronomy SE, though it might be a duplicate there.

Comment: You might also check first to see if the naming of these objects is already clearly explained in Wiipedia.

Comment: Oh okay, i thought this fit here that's why I posted it but I'll shift if required

Comment: @uhoh I did check Wiki and IAU and other websites but none of them gave any fixed rules or laws related to the naming of celestial objects

Comment: [The IAU website has a naming conventions page](https://www.iau.org/public/themes/naming/)

Comment: From Wikipedia [When it was discovered it was the first such pulsar known. The prevailing theoretical explanation for the system implied that **the companion is being destroyed by the strong powerful outflows, or winds, of high-energy particles caused by the neutron star, and so the sobriquet black widow was applied to the object**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Widow_Pulsar)  and also from Wikipedia [**Arrokoth was named for a word in the Powhatan language of the Tidewater region of Virginia and Maryland**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/486958_Arrokoth#Arrokoth)

Comment: Let's quickly vote to close this so it can be migrated to Astronomy SE where it will be on-topic and likely receive some good answers.

Comment: Welcome new user, please ask on Astronomy.

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 as I said, I did go through that and no where does it mention how to name such objects. There was no definite law there, and not even the slightest mention on why an object (like Black Widow Pulsar) is named the way it is named